# How to change search URL in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, search, urlencode, permalinks, query-string

I want to change the search url to something like this

```
http://simply.mmag.in/blog/?s=coaching
```

Where as my current search result shows which is recommended by most user and article

```
http://simply.mmag.in/blog/coaching
```

Code which i am using for the above search result

```
function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

and the base url code

```
function re_rewrite_rules() {
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->search_base = 'blog';
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 're_rewrite_rules');
```

How can i get search result like this

```
http://simply.mmag.in/blog/?s=coaching
```

Answer (score 0):

What happends if you just remove or comment out your `wpb_change_search_url()` function?

Comment: (i can't use comments yet since i just made this account, so i had to post an answer)

Comment: If i removed this then the search result goes back to default wordpress search url

Comment: what if you change ur function from wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) ); to wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );

Comment: I had even try that but it redirects me to the blog page only instead of search result page

Comment: The url changed to http://simply.mmag.in/blog/?s=coaching this but the instead of search result goes to blog page

Comment: and what if you change ur re_rewrite_rules() function from $wp_rewrite->search_base = 'blog'; to $wp_rewrite->search_base = 'blog/?s=';

Comment: Even in that case it is redirected to the blog page

Comment: ok one last try, keep the wpd_change_search_url() function and add the wp_redirect( home_url( "/blog/?s=" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );.

then try to comment out the re_rewrite_rules() function. because you basically have 2 functions to rewrite it to /blog/

Comment: I tried that but still its not working. I comment out the rewrite function and kept only wpb_change_search_url but still it redirects to the blog page where as the url changed to http://simply.mmag.in/blog/?s=coaching

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just remove this custom code? Wordpress by default uses ?s= in urls, and code used by you just rewrite it.

Comment: If i removed this function wpb_change_search_url() code then it backs to normal default search result which i dont want. and if i remove the rewrite code then the search not work properly